# auto rotate screen Lenovo x380 yoga

Tags: lenovo, tablet

I've installed [these scripts](https://github.com/wassname/thinkpad-x380-yoga-scripts) to fix some issues on my Lenovo laptop (running Xubuntu 18.04).

When running the "status" commands under the Manual Installation section there seems to be a problem with the last part: For yoga-rotate@${USER}.service the output in my terminal is

```
● yoga--rotate@marco.service - [ThinkPad Yoga] Rotation with accelerometer
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/yoga-rotate@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-24 18:52:07 EDT; 4s ago
      Process: 10067 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python2 /opt/thinkpad-x380-yoga-scripts/rotate/thinkpad-rotate.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 10067 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The solid dot at the beginning is grey, while for the other status commands they appear green. Not surprisingly, my screen does not rotate when I turn to tablet mode. Running the enable and start commands did not return any errors. At this point I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Have you tried to launch the Python script manually and see if it prints any error?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I just tried it, I entered "python thinkpad-rotate.py" in the terminal and I got the error message "Can't find an accelerator device!".